# How do I redirect using "xyz snippet" in a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [xyz-snippet](https://xyzscripts.com/wordpress-plugins/xyz-wp-insert-code-snippet/details) to insert some php code (post forms and handling post requests) in some Wordpress pages. In the work I am doing it is necessary to take input from a user (with a post form) and process it and redirect them to another page depending on their input. I tried the `header()` function and it didn't work now I am trying this:

```
if (empty($entry)){
        echo('<h1>I am empty and should be redirecting now</h1>');
        $url = 'https://jimmyshapopi.com';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;}
```

This is not working. I know my logic is fine because that `<h1>` tag actually prints but the redirect is not working.

XYZ PHP Snippet, uses shortcodes for you to enter you php code into a page. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't redirect once you output. `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). You could try outputting a JS redirect.

Comment: you can try and output `echo '<script>window.location.href= "' . $url . '";</script>';`. But the Status Code is still 200 and not 30*

Comment: The JS worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Sysix and @user3783243 for the answer.

The workaround is to use JavaScript. Echo some JavaScript that changes the window.loaction. The JavaScript code is:

```
    window.location.href = url
```

Since this needs to be written in the context of a PHP script you need to `echo` a `<script>` tag like this:

```php
echo '<script>window.location.href= "' . $url . '";</script>';
```

In this context the `$url` variable is defined in the PHP code and not in the JavaScript.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.